# Getting a String of enum Names in a single line

Tags: enums

What's the way to get the names of enum elements names as an array of Strings?

I have an enum as below

```
public enum1{
APP_ID("12345"),CUSTOMER_NAME("Custname");

private String enumValue;
enum1(String value){
this.enumValue = value;}

public String value(){
return enumValue;}
```

}

methodCall usage:
    getMethod( //String of enumnames to be passed from here without a loop );

Unfortunately I cannot do much to change the way this is designed, but need to pass
a string of the enum values ( Here, "12345", "Custname") in an array to another method 
and not the enumNames from enum.values() .

Note: The below solutions do not pass enumnames.Hence are not useful to me.Neither is a loop conversion of value to name individually.

```
EnumUtils.getEnumMap( enum1.class).keySet();

EnumUtils.getEnumList(enum1.class);

enum1.values();
```

wish Java enums had a names() method, like the values().

Comment: Why don't you implement it yourself?

Comment: `String[] names = Arrays.stream(enum1.values()).map(enum1:: value).toArray(String[]::new);`